# How to create many nodes and relationships with Neo4j.Driver.V1

Tags: c#, neo4j

I have a C# object model that I want to persist with Neo4j. It contains dozens of Projects, which each has 1000-4000 children. I currently use the official C# driver, but I could switch to something else. Doing this one child at a time is, unsurprisingly, inefficient. This takes several minutes for one project:

```
        foreach (var service in project.Services)
        {
            using (var session = _driver.Session())
            {
                var query = "MATCH (p:Project) WHERE ID(p) = " + neoId +
                            " CREATE (ds:Service {name:\"" + service.Name +
                            "\"})<-[:HAS_SERVICE]-(p)";
                var result = session.Run(query);
            }
        }
```

I'm a Cypher noob, but I gather that I should probably pass the children as parameters to a query involving `UNWIND` or `FOREACH`, but it's not clear to me how that would happen programmatically as the optional second parameter to `Run()` is either a `Dictionary` or an `object` (not clear how that object will be interpreted).
So, how to do this efficently from C#?

Comment: Where the variable `neoId` is defined?

Comment: `neoId` is a long. The code is just a snippet, to give an idea what I want to accomplish. No `project`or `_driver` defined either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) First you need to create a dictionary with an array of names of services.

2) And inside query expand them using UNWIND.

```
var servicesNames_ = new List<string>();
foreach (var service in project.Services)
{
    servicesNames_.Add( service.Name );
}
var servicesName = servicesNames_.ToArray();

var params = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
    {"services", servicesName},
    {"neoId", neoId}
};

using (var session = _driver.Session())
{
    var query = "WITH {neoId} as neoId, {services} as services " +
                "MATCH (p:Project) WHERE ID(p) = {neoId} " +
                "UNWIND services as serviceName " + 
                "CREATE (ds:Service {name: serviceName})<-[:HAS_SERVICE]-(p) ";
    var result = session.Run(query, params);
}
```